# Uninstalling SQL Server 2005 express - blue screen

Tags: sql-server-2005, uninstall

Few months ago, I installed sql server 2005 express edition. When I am trying to uninstall it, it keeps throwing a blue screen saying, the subsystem system has terminated unexpectedly 000x...Is there a way to uninstall sql server 2005 express. Does the blue screen error mean any files relating to the uninstall are missing?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has published a lengthy KB article on how to manually uninstall SQL Server 2005 (applies to Express):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909967

There are log files that can be generated during most steps that would be helpful in diagnosing the problem, if the manual method does not work.